# Codeigniter: $_SESSION doesn't work on hosting server

Tags: php, codeigniter

Code works fine on my localhost but it is giving error when I moved project to hosting server. It says

```
Severity: Notice  --> Undefined variable: _SESSION
```

I am using Codeigniter 2.1.3. Double checked `$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session');` in autoload.php

Comment: This happens if you've neglected to call `session_start`. Are you sure you've called it?

Comment: are you actually using the session class? http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html - $this->session->set_userdata() ... etc

Comment: Call `session_start()`.

Comment: If you are using $_SESSION then no need to load `$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');` because you are not using CI session, if you want to use CI session then use  `($this->session->userdata('some_data'))`. get full help from user guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$_SESSION is not available until session_start() is called. I would recommend using the native CI session class function (**$this->session->userdata('some_data')**) instead of using the default PHP sessions. CI doesn’t use php session’s and instead rely’s on cookies. To amend this notice you can add session_start() to the index.php file if you wish to continue with what you are doing.